# Getting Error while calling a url from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, action

I am creating an action using a vf page that automatically redirects to a url.But,I am getting this error.

My code is as follows :

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" action="https://composer.congamerge.com?sessionId={!API.Session_ID} 
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290} 
&id={!Lead.Id} 
&TemplateId=a0EU000000nQdXr">
</apex:page>
```

Error message : [image]

Comment: You need to use `$` sign before `API`. Like `{!$API.Partner_Server_URL_290}`

Comment: @tandonprateek you should add that comment as an answer =D

Comment: OK Let me do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$` sign before API. Like `{!$API.Partner_Server_URL_290}`.

Comment: Please mark this as answered.